# Removing the object type from the list of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have the following class in nodejs:

```
let id;
let totalCalls;
let totalMinutes;

class callVolume { 
    constructor(id){ 
      this.id = id;
      this.totalCalls = 0;
      this.totalMinutes = 0;
    }
}

module.exports = callVolume;
```

on my callService.js file I import this class and if I create an object using the constructor:

```
const callVolume = require('./callVolume');
let call = new callVolume(1);
```

If I console log call object it shows:

```
callVolume {
              "id": 1,
              "totalCalls" : 0,
              "totalMinutes" : 0
           }
```

and if there is a list it keeps repeating the class name callVolume:

```
[callVolume {
              "id": 1,
              "totalCalls" : 0,
              "totalMinutes" : 0
           },
 callVolume {
              "id": 1,
              "totalCalls" : 0,
              "totalMinutes" : 0
           }]
```

I don't even know why is showing that, is there any way I can remove that. I would like to have something like this:

```
          [{
              "id": 1,
              "totalCalls" : 0,
              "totalMinutes" : 0
           },
           {
              "id": 1,
              "totalCalls" : 0,
              "totalMinutes" : 0
           }]
```

Method I wrote to compare two list of objects:

```
const compareJsonObjects = function(firstList, secondList) {
  if(firstList.length != secondList.length) return false
  else {
    for(i = 0; i<firstList.length; i++) {
      if(firstList[i].id != secondList[i].id) return false;
      if(firstList[i].totalCalls != secondList[i].totalCalls) return false;
      if(firstList[i].totalMinutes != secondList[i].totalMinutes) return false;
    }
   return true;
  }
```

Comment: @TylerRoper I wrote a method to compare two objects going through each property inside the objects but this is returning false when I pass an object created by constructor and another one created let obj = {} obj.id = 1, obj.totalCalls =0, obj.totalMinutes = 0

Comment: Please share that method.

Comment: added my method

Comment: It would be helpful to see *how* you're calling the method too. But again, that is only the constructor name. It has no effect. It would change nothing at all in the function you've provided. Your mistake is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just the debugger informing you of the type of object, or rather what class it originates from. If you want to it to just be a pure object without the constructor property pointing at the class, you can use `Object.assign`.

```
let call = Object.assign({}, new callVolume(1));
```

This will make a bare copy and transfer values from the class instance into an object.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really did the trick. The constructor property is gone and when I pass these objects to compare method now is validating correct.

Comment: *"when I pass these objects to compare method now is validating correct"* - Please realize that the constructor name would have no effect whatsoever on your comparison function. Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/1075bjhk/).

Comment: @TylerRoper yes, yes you are correct. Looking further on my code I noticed that method was validating that as not valid because my data objects were not identical. They all have same values but one property was coming as a string and on the other object was an integer, so it makes sense to validate that as false. Thank you for insisting on your statement and making me look deeper in my code.

Comment: @DoArNa And thank you for taking the time to confirm! I appreciate the kind words. Glad you were able to sort it out - have a great night.